# How to display a JSON API as an Array?

Tags: php, json, api, decode

I'm just trying to display an API response as an Array, but something is wrong and I don't find it:

The API's answer:

```
{"status":"OK","minecrafts":[{"id":411,"ip":"2452453","name":"EdenCraft","port":23,"ram":512,"leaf_id":1522,"ftp_password":"1231235312","subscription_end":"2014-02-06T19:56:29.000Z"}]}
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.edenservers.fr/minecraft?user_id=id&api_key=key";
$data = file_get_contents($url); // Opening the Query URL
$data = json_decode($data, true); // Decoding the obtained JSON data
if(count($data) > 0) {
    foreach($data as $rank => $donnees) {
        echo "<u>" . $rank ."</u> : ". $rank;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Rien n'a &eacute;t&eacute; trou&eacute;.";
}
?>
```

And this is what's showed on my Dashboard:

```
status : status

minecrafts : minecrafts
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  if(is_array($val)){
       foreach($val[0] as $key1=>$val1){
          echo "<u>" . $key1 ."</u> : ". $val1;
       } 
   }else{
           echo "<u>" . $key ."</u> : ". $val;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
echo "<u>" . $rank ."</u> : ". $rank
```

to:

```
echo "<u>" . $rank ."</u> : ". print_r( $donnees, TRUE )
```

Or the other way around if you want the values reversed.  But the issue is with using `$rank` in both places.

Comment: Looks like it's a multi-dimensional array, so `$donnees` itself is still an array instead of a string in certain cases. The edit I made above should solve that, though you'll have to modify it (such as perhaps including a nested `foreach()` to loop through it) based on how you want the output formatted.